# How to choose the right map projections for flight plan?

Tags: theory

There are 2 projection of maps that I saw online. UK CAA is a transverse projection map, while ICAO maps are conical.

It seems that transverse map is easier for flight planing as straight lines are rhumb lines, on the other hand the shortest route between two point is the great circle which is curved. So it's easy to calculate a heading, but it will not be the best route.

In conical map the straight lines are the Great circles so the best route, but its harder to calculate heading for flight.

What should be chosen and why? I didn't found info about the in the Internet...

Comment: Over what distance? Long flights this may make a difference, but for a couple hundred miles it may not be worth it. Typically winds aloft will have more effect

Comment: It all depends on how long is your path and if it includes polar regions or not. This is typically a question for [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=pcs).

Comment: If it's the transverse Mercator projection, rhumb lines are NOT straight. They are in the Mercator projection. I don't know of any conic projections that have straight great circle lines between any 2 points. Maybe it's a gnomonic projection?

Comment: Are you planning on dead reckoning the whole way? Or will you (if the flight is long enough to warrant it) look at the great circle route and then pick some nav aids along that route for your actual flight plan?

Comment: @mkennedy: "*Maybe it's a gnomonic*", [yes](https://flylib.com/books/2/366/1/html/2/images/0596007035/figs/maph_0333.gif) and [why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gnomonic.png).

Comment: @mins Gnomonic displays great circle paths as straight lines. Other common azimuthal/planar projections like stereographic and azimuthal equidistant don't except if they're centered at a pole and the line passes through or ends at the pole.